# Fourth level menu option not working

Tags: android, menu

I am using a fourth level Active Menu on my app, everything works perfect but when I select one item on the Menu fourth level, the system is not calling `onOptionsItemSelected` anymore, so I can't get the selected item on my app.

Here is my code

EDIT 1: the dash `-` in the Id's are making confusion, I am removing them from the code. Sorry for that

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// .... some code
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Level1: {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Level 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       break;
    }
    case R.id.Level2: {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Level 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       break;
    }
    case R.id.Level3: {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Level 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       break;
    }
    case R.id.Level4: {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Level 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       break;
    }}
    return true;
}
```

and here the XML file `main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item  android:id="@+id/Level1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/Level1">
    <menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/Level2"
          android:title="@string/Level2">
          <menu>
          <item android:id="@+id/Level3"
              android:title="@string/Level3">
              <menu>
              <item android:id="@+id/Level4"
                  android:title="@string/Level4"/>
              </menu>
          </item>
          </menu>
    </item>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

I was reading the documentation but it doesn't states a limit for nested sub-menus.

Finally my solution was to append a `android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected"` to the fourth level item like:

```
              <menu>
              <item android:id="@+id/Level4"
                  android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected"
                  android:title="@string/Level4"/>
              </menu>
```

to force the call to `onOptionItemSelected`, it works but is there a better solution???

EDIT 2: I just found that this walk-around doesn't works with Android version 4.0.3 or earlier.!!! not even using `onMenuItemSelected`...!!!

Now I am in problem, please help...!!

Comment: `case R.id.Level-1`? I didn't know `-` is allowed in there.

Comment: Should you even be using - in IDs? Isn't it giving weird results in the switch by ID? Such as looking for an ID named 'Level' and subtracting 1 from it's integer ID?
Have you tried making your IDs not use - ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the "-" actually my app is not like this, I wrote down this code just for the question. Any way the issue is that the fourth sub-menu is not called when selected.